# Worker Pool in Spacelift showing as 0 workers

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, spacelift

I created a private worker using https://github.com/spacelift-io/terraform-aws-spacelift-workerpool-on-ec2

However, my worker pool shows as 0 even though I can see the worker in my AWS Console. What could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is due to wrong values being passed, specifically these:

**SPACELIFT_TOKEN** - the token you’ve received from Spacelift on worker pool creation ( this would be in a file called worker-pool-x.config)

**SPACELIFT_POOL_PRIVATE_KEY** - the contents of the private key file you generated, in base64.

However, I will list out all the variables and where to get them from, If you are saving them in a Spacelift stack then they would be prefixed with TF_VAR_

- **TF_VAR_worker_pool_id** - the worker pool id, you can copy this value from the worker pool page
- **TF_VAR_worker_pool_private_key** - you can get this by running the command `cat spacelift.key | base64 -w 0` in your command line. For Mac users, the command is `cat spacelift.key | base64 -b 0`.
- **TF_VAR_worker_pool_config** - This will be the contents of the .config file that was downloaded when you created your worker
  pool.(this is the same as the SPACELIFT_TOKEN previously mentioned)
- **TF_VAR_spacelift_api_key_endpoint** - account api endpoint eg https://.app.spacelift.io
- **TF_VAR_spacelift_api_key_id** You can create an API key by navigating to organization settings > create key. After the key is created, you can copy its id.
- **TF_VAR_spacelift_api_key_secret** - Once you create the API key, you can find the secret in the config file.
- **TF_VAR_worker_pool_security_groups** & **TF_VAR_worker_pool_subnets** will be the security group and subnets you want to use.